# Переезд с Subversion на GIT под Windows

Tags: git, git-svn

Анамнез: 
на протяжении более 5 лет наша команда разработчиков использует SVN возникла идея переехать на GIT, так как часто возникает нужда работать отдельно от основной команды разработчиков и увидели спасение в "локальных комитах". Самая большая беда в том, что для переезда на GIT мы можем использовать только свой собственный сервер под управлением MS W Server 2008 R2 Foundation (репозиторий SVN находится на корпоративном сервере под линухом) по ряду причин перевести форточный сервер под пингвинов нельзя (функционал винды на нем необходим).

Задачи:

1. скопировать рабочий репозиторий с svnserver (сервер репозитория Subversion под управлением Debian) в репозиторий GIT на gitserver (под управлением Win Server 2008).
2. обеспечить команде разработчиков доступ к репозиторию GIT (который есть клон репозитория SVN).

Предпринятые попытки:
С задачей за номером 1 я справился тут все оказалось просто:

- в git bash набираем:

  ```
  ~$ git svn clone svn://<server_name>:<repository_name>
  ```

  (хотя может чуточку не так, мог и подзабыть уже 2 месяца мучаюсь) и вводим логин пароль для прописанного в svn-репозитории пользователя.
- после чего с помощью `git svn fetch` и `git svn rebase` забираю новые комиты из SVN-а.

А вот задача номер 2 ох бабоньки лягла на плечи мои и не дает мне горемычному покоя (простите за вольность).
В общем поднял я на виндовом сервере OpenSSH открыл 22 порт в брандмауэре а дальше понять могу уже тонну манов выкурил что скоро рак мозга заработаю (а может и уже).
При попытке с удаленной машины клонировать GIT репозиторй выдается окно: от TortoiseGIT PLink (это SSH клиент тортойсовский) "git@gitserver password:" c инпутбаром для ввода пароля (только пароль, логин не запрашивает) какие бы пароли не подсовывал не пускает клонировать все одно твердит: "Access Denied". Притом поведение всегда одно и тоже, что на машине для которой сгенерирована пара RSA-ключей и (далее судя по всему идет мое кривое понимание работы SSH сервера) текст из файла .pub добавлен в файл ssh_host_rsa_key.pub что для машины на которой пара ключей даже не генерировалась, то есть аутентификация на SSH-сервере не проходит, сколько не рылся в манах никак не могу найти внятной информации о том каким путем в принципе происходит аутентификация в репозитории GIT.

В общем подмогните, тону, а в какую сторону грести не понимаю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте код в вопросе (Ctrl+K), а то очень сложно читается. Ну и списки/абзацы. Половину я немного поправил, чтобы было понятно, о чём речь.

Comment: Кстати, раз уж у вас был сервер svn на debian и явно кто-то умеет его админить, зачем вы сервер git делаете на винде? Боюсь, это вам может добавить хлопот.

Comment: Сорри, впервые пишу на этом форуме (с подобным движком в принципе) потому с форматированием сообщений не разобрался пока.

Comment: Здесь используется Markdown (как и на GitHub, например). Справка тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: К сожалению сервером под Debian воспользоваться не могу, когда-то самолично этот сервер держал, но теперь он от нас уплыл, проблемы индейца вождя не волнуют, потому никто не будет нам на нем GIT поднимать, выхода нет, придется кровь из носу виндовый сервант использовать, с линухами было бы проще намного ибо манов внятных и разных много, а вот о том как GIT с виндой дружить ничего внятного не нашел.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Разрешите поинтересоваться, а чем вам ветки в SVN не подходят для workflow?

Comment: Полезная статья: «[Переезд проекта с SVN на Git](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144626/)».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решал недавно похожую задачу: имеем Windows Server 2008 x64, необходимо переехать с SVN (на этом же сервере) на GIT.

Решил следующим образом:

1. Поскольку SVN далее не планировалось поддерживать, то использовал утилиту [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git). Сперва устанавливаем [Ruby](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), в процессе установки для простоты отмечаем пункт "Add Ruby executables to your PATH".
2. Запускаем командную строку с правами администратора и выполняем `gem install svn2git`. Должно всё успешно установиться в каталог установки Ruby.
3. Далее используем svn2git с нужными параметрами (их список и документация доступны на GitHub в описании проекта). Для корректного переноса авторов коммитов необходимо создать простой текстовый файл (обязательно в кодировке `UTF-8 without BOM`) в формате:

   `pavel = Pavel Sidorov <p.sidorov@gmail.com>`
   `sergey = Sergey Ivanov <s.ivanov@gmail.com>`

   И указать путь к этому файлу в аргументе `--authors`.
4. По завершении выполнения утилиты получаем локальный GIT-репозиторий. Следующий шаг - предоставить удаленный доступ к этому репозиторию. Для этого я использовал [Bonobo Git Server](https://bonobogitserver.com/), процесс установки подробно описан со скриншотами на странице [install](https://bonobogitserver.com/install/). Предварительно обязательно проверить требования и установить недостающие компоненты.
5. После установки создаем удалённый репозиторий и выкладываем наш локальный конвертированный репозиторий:

   `git remote add origin https://172.1.1.1:8094/MyProject.git`
   `git push origin master`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую ваш метод, о результатах отпишусь

Answer (score 3):

Огромное спасибо Pavel Parshin, воспользовался вашим советом, теперь все подготовлено для переезда:

1. BonoboGitServer устанавливается в танце "2 притопа 3 прихлопа" бубен нужен разве что только для антуража на сайте разработчика подробное описание всех па. В общем читайте пост Павла выше, там даны все ссылки.
2. Вот только не стал я пользоваться утилитой svn2git, не было задачи сопоставления имен старых svn-овских комитеров с новыми (они и так совпадают, да и персона по логину идентифицируется однозначно) потому я просто клонировал через гит репозиторий subversion:

   `~$ git svn clone svn://[servername]/[repositoryname]`

далее заходим в админку Bonobo и на вкладке "Репозитории" находим нашего мигранта, добавляем ему описание и раздаем права доступа.
Далее ждем часа Х, выполняем на сервере GIT в директории репозитория мигранта:

```
~$ git svn fetch  
~$ git svn rebase
```

Делаем:
РАЗ - Закрываем доступ к репозиторию svn.
ДВА - В репозитории мигранте на сервере GIT правим корневой .git/config меняя значение bare с false на true.
ТРИ - Ну и все, как завещал Афоня: "Можете пользоваться!"©

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое, и наиболее типично используемое в небольших локальных сетях - открываете общий доступ к папке, добавляете права на чтение и/или запись нужным пользователям - собственно и всё. Без всяких неродных для Windows ssh, bash'а и прочих.

Ещё есть несколько вариантов, доступных при включенной роли веб-сервера(IIS):

1. Предоставьте пользователям доступ через через стандартный [git-http-backend](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend).
2. Разверните какой-нибудь веб-интерфейс для GIT, например [Bonobo Git Server](https://bonobogitserver.com/) или [GitWeb](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb).
3. Установите полноценную систему управления проектами, поддерживающую хостинг GIT-репозиториев - [Microsoft Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx) (есть бесплатная версия для небольших команд), [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), либо [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/).

А вообще, можете не мучатся с установкой/настройкой чего-то у себя, и просто разместить репозиторий на [GitHub](https://github.com/)(требуют небольшую плату за закрытые репозитории) либо [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)(закрытые репозитории бесплатны для команд до 5 человек).

Comment: Спасибо, через общий доступ (Samba) как я понял из описания GIT нужны танцы с бубном для открытия доступа на запись в репозиторий по протоколу file:// танцы фиг с ними беда в том что в локалке форменный бардак, пользователи в домене, наш сервер (который для GITа) в группе с этим часто возникает трабл с заходом на шару из под доменной машины на машину в группе и наоборот.  С IIS варианты интересней, однако так же из описания GITа нужно прикручивать HTTPs для комита или плясать чтобы разрешить комиты по HTTP. Пока попробую поковырять в сторону GitLab, у него вроде лицензия наиболее вменяемая

Comment: пардон, комитами называю пуши по инерции от подрывника.

Comment: @Annemesski, не нужно никаких "танцев с бубнами" - ни для разрешения записи в репозиторий через общий доступ(ничем не отличается от обычных папок в Windows; проще кстати использовать не `file://`, а UNC пути с прямыми слешами - `//server/repositories/project.git`), ни для работы без HTTPS(по умолчанию, в 1 и 2 из предложенных мною вариантов с IIS, используется именно обычный HTTP). Не скинете ли ссылку на ту "документацию", в которой об таких странностях пишут? :)

Comment: Чтоб я помнил где и каким местом я про это читал, что-то из доморощеных вариаций на тему "GIT - это просто", скорее всего что-то криво понял. В общем решил проблему с помощью HTTP-сервера, ниже отписал что да как.